# $_SESSION[] in the function PHP

Tags: php, function

how to add $_SESSION[] in function

```
function get_cart_list()
{
    global $_SESSION['items'];
    if (isset($_SESSION['items'])) 
    {
        foreach ($_SESSION['items'] as $key => $val)
        {
            $gete = $key;
            $total = 0;
            include ('gc-cache-product.php');
            $jumlah_harga = ( $skupricenew ) * $val;
            $total += $jumlah_harga;
            include ($themeid."/content/part/cart/cart_list_item.php");
        }
    }
}
```

syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ',' or ';' in **/home/clients/xxx/html/website/template/shadows/gc-cart.php** on line 2

thank you

Comment: include inside a loop, is usually a bad idea

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, `$_SESSION` is a [superglobal](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php). It's already global; you don't need to explicitly say you're using it as a global. From [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php):

> This is a 'superglobal', or automatic global, variable. This simply means that it is available in all scopes throughout a script. There is no need to do `global $variable;` to access it within functions or methods.

Second, you can't use an array element with `global`. It's just `global $foo;`, not `global $foo['bar'];`. That's why you get a syntax error.

In the future, when you get errors like this, you may want to refer to [this reference question and its answers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12769982/2057919).